# Why x='b'*4 is greater than y='a'*5 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I do not remember where I saw this code but I had made a note of this and now I got back to it and I do not get why the result is "greater".

```
x='b'*4
y='a'*5
if x == y:
print("Equal")

elif x<y:
print("Less")

elif x>y:
print("Greater")
```

Is this a matter of index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REPL usually helps with these kinds of questions:

```py
>>> 'b'*4 > 'a'*5
True
>>> 'b'*4
'bbbb'
>>> 'a'*5
'aaaaa'
>>> 'bbbb' > 'aaaaa'
True
```

So the question is really why `'bbbb' > 'aaaaa'` is true. The answer is because they are strings, and strings are compared in alphabetical order. If these were words in a dictionary, `'bbbb'` would appear after `'aaaaa'`.

Answer (score 0):

Because 
`'b'*4` equals `'bbbb'`
and `a*5` equals `'aaaaa'`

'b' has a greater unicode value than 'a'

Answer (score 0):

"b" will always be greater than "a" * n, because string comparison works by comparing the very first character of the string with their ASCII value.

It doesn't matter how many "a"'s there are, because b will always be greater than the first "a" in the string.

However, if the first character are identical, then it will compare the next character, and so on.